# jQuery delay between allowed mouseover + time mouse needs to be over for

Tags: jquery, timer, hover, spam

I want to be able to stop people spamming their mouse over the object to stop it fading in and out. At the moment if you spam across it it will just build a back log of events to do. I want to be able to stop it getting spammed by a delay (so that you hover over and off but it wont rehover and off for lets say 3 seconds) and then i also want to set how long the mouse needs to be on the object before it will run the function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find("span").fadeIn("slow");
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).find("span").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plug-in. Fast and easy!

Answer (score 2):

This is very common, you're best bet is to use this tiny (1.4 Kb) plug in:

[jQuery Hover Intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

It solves that problem and you can specify for how long. After you include the plug in, you just have to change `.hover()` to `hoverIntent()`.

Of course there are other solutions like using `.stop()` method, like this:

```
$(".image").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).stop().find("span").fadeIn("slow");
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).stop().find("span").fadeOut("slow");
        }
);
```

If you want to know more about it read this article: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup